# How to get message flags like "seen" in Gmail API

Tags: gmail-api

I'm trying to get email messages from Gmail using the RESTful API and I don't see how can I get message flags (read / unread and etc.). 
Is there any way to get message flags from the Gmail using the RESTful API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by "flags" and "folders"?  are you used to using IMAP and referring to it in that sense?  what you normally would want is to look at labels like "UNREAD".  those labels are the hardcoded, system labels and are documented at:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels

they are those exact values, never translated to other languages like the web *user* interface is.

gmail doesn't have "flags" or "folders" just labels.  the flags and folder concepts are (somewhat hackily) provided to support IMAP.  if you want to see all the unread message in the inbox just do something like:

```
>>> messages.list(labelIds=["INBOX", "UNREAD'])
```

Comment: Yes, I used to work with an IMAP and now migrating from it to the Gmail RESTFul API. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Read/Unread status for a message is indicated by the presence of the UNREAD label.  You can also see whether a message is starred.  See [Managing Labels](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels).

Comment: Interesting, if I can rely on the label names ? Are they same for any language or UNERAD is just for English ? And also I was thinking that in the list of labels that I get from Message I see only labels (folders) but now I have to filter out "folders" and flags. Very confusing - IMHO. Thanks anyway, it was helpful.

Comment: "Folders and flags" are IMAP concepts, they don't map well to Gmail.  Gmail IMAP does it's best to conform to IMAP standard but it's not always obvious.  In Gmail, everything is labels even INBOX and UNREAD.  Those system label IDs are standard and don't change: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels

Comment: @SlavaG yes, it appears the label names are as shown in [the docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels), and not translated in the API

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as:

```
ListMessagesResponse emails = service.users().messages().list("me").setQ("label:UNREAD").execute();
// Getting my unread mails.
```

And it works with whatever language.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking, I wanted to get all messages and their flags, and not only unread messages. Using labels to build a flags is ugly :) .