# Read email in MVC web application - how let know Gmail inbox that email was read?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gmail-api

I set up in my MVC web application that gets all my emails from my Gmail inbox (via the Gmail API).

After I read an email in my MVC web application how can I let my Gmail inbox know that the email was read & shouldn't be marked as an unread email?

Comment: What do the api docs say?

Comment: Add the `read` label.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get message flags like "seen" in Gmail API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936724/how-to-get-message-flags-like-seen-in-gmail-api)

Comment: my question is how to notify Gmail that the message was read? actually, how do I notify Gmail with any changes like deleted an email,send an email ... I just know how to get the info from Gmail but not how to send update Gmail, thanx:)